# Rename files in Azure Blob Container

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have files uploaded to Azure Blob Container. I want to rename the files using DotNet Core Web API without re-uploading the files.

Comment: I think this is impossible, the blob storage api doesn't have such method.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found to achieve my objective

You need to install "Azure.Storage.Blobs" NuGet first

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Rename")]
public async Task Rename([FromBody] List<FileToRename> files)
{
    string connStr = "<Azure Blob Connection String>";
  
    BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connStr, files[0].ContainerName);

    foreach (FileToRename file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            BlobClient sourceBlob = container.GetBlobClient(file.SourceFilename);

            // Ensure that the source blob exists.
            if (await sourceBlob.ExistsAsync())
            {
                // Lease the source blob for the copy operation
                // to prevent another client from modifying it.
                BlobLeaseClient lease = sourceBlob.GetBlobLeaseClient();
                // Specifying -1 for the lease interval creates an infinite lease.
                await lease.AcquireAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));

                // Get the source blob's properties and display the lease state.
                BlobProperties sourceProperties = await sourceBlob.GetPropertiesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Lease state: {sourceProperties.LeaseState}");

                // Get a BlobClient representing the destination blob with a unique name.
                BlobClient destBlob = container.GetBlobClient(file.DestinationFilename);

                // Start the copy operation.
                await destBlob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceBlob.Uri);

                // Update the source blob's properties.
                sourceProperties = await sourceBlob.GetPropertiesAsync();

                if (sourceProperties.LeaseState == LeaseState.Leased)
                {
                    // Break the lease on the source blob.
                    await lease.BreakAsync();

                    // Update the source blob's properties to check the lease state.
                    sourceProperties = await sourceBlob.GetPropertiesAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Lease state: {sourceProperties.LeaseState}");
                }
            }

            await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
            file.IsSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            file.IsSuccess = false;
            file.Message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```